# Heroku Error H13 on ExpressJS Node HTTPS Server

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku, https, express

I'm trying to implement HTTPS on my Node.js server (Expressjs framework).  I have my signed certificate and key, as well as a self-signed cert/key for testing/development:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production'){
  var app = module.exports = express.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/nopass_server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.crt')
  });
} else {
  var app = module.exports = express.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/self_signed/nopass_server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/self_signed/server.crt')
  });
}
```

I've also setup SSL Endpoint on Heroku. Everything works fine on `localhost`, and Endpoint seems to be working properly, but when I run the app in production (on Heroku) I get an H13 application error.  Interestingly (or not) if I tell express to create an HTTP server instead: `var app = module.exports = express.createServer()` it works, but then Chrome complains that `the page at https://mydomain.com ran insecure content from http://mydomain.com`.

Can I not/should I not be creating an HTTPS server in express for production? If I should, is there something extra I need to make it work on Heroku (e.g. I'm trusting it to set the correct port with `var port = process.env.PORT`)? If not, how can I serve "secure" content if its not running an https server so browsers won't complain?

I'm using the following to take care of any non-https requests:

```
app.get('*',function(req,res,next){
  if(req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] != 'https'){
    res.redirect('https://mydomain.com'+req.url);
  } else next();
});
```

This is currently located just above the rest of my routes, could this be the issue/should this be somewhere else?

I have very limited experience with https in general so I'm probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SSL termination occurs at Heroku's load balancers; they send your app plain (non-SSL) traffic, so your app should create a non-HTTPS server. As for `the page at https://mydomain.com ran insecure content from http://mydomain.com`, make sure that all the images/scripts/etc. your page is using is also served over the `https` protocol.

Comment: Non-https it is, thanks!  It turns out that something within the jquery-ui css was causing the warning, even though I was hosting the code on my server. Pulling it from the https google cdn instead got rid of the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app.enable('trust proxy')`, then `req.secure` works also on Heroku.