# what does error status 413 in node.js, heroku mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have a node.js app that works fine locally but when i run in at heroku it quits, I status 0 or status 143 does anyone understand what this can mean?

```
2015-04-14T21:14:41.428508+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by
josef@actionist.se
2015-04-14T21:14:41.569626+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-04-14T21:14:44.101446+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-04-14T21:14:45.789499+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2015-04-14T21:14:45.675609+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-04-14T21:14:47.559184+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
2015-04-14T21:14:47.559208+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
2015-04-14T21:14:49.398042+00:00 app[web.1]: Node app is running at localhost:26268
2015-04-14T21:14:49.825551+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-04-14T21:16:05.765151+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy bcb1918 by josef@actionist.se
2015-04-14T21:16:05.765151+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by josef@actionist.se
2015-04-14T21:16:06.234464+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-04-14T21:16:09.804498+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-04-14T21:16:10.788591+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2015-04-14T21:16:11.515039+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-04-14T21:16:12.732654+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
2015-04-14T21:16:12.732736+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
2015-04-14T21:16:13.951425+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-14T21:16:13.951416+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-14T21:16:13.951422+00:00 app[web.1]: > party@0.1.3 start /app
2015-04-14T21:16:13.951424+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2015-04-14T21:16:15.479452+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2015-04-14T21:16:15.494024+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-04-14T21:17:13.883207+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10     desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/host=actionistcookalong.herokuapp.com request_id=a5f2ce21-21bd-43ac-8434-9eb39282c542 fwd="178.78.232.172" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-14T21:21:01.044982+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-04-14T21:21:05.040510+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2015-04-14T21:21:06.954809+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
2015-04-14T21:21:06.954834+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
2015-04-14T21:21:07.605924+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-14T21:21:07.605931+00:00 app[web.1]: > party@0.1.3 start /app
2015-04-14T21:21:07.605933+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2015-04-14T21:21:07.605935+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-14T21:21:08.874268+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-04-14T21:21:08.868440+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help but as far as i know status 143 is an exit code. Maybe look at the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631536/https-node-js-application-on-heroku

Comment: Actually Heroku was stopping everything two lines up and that's why you see the 143 return as a result of them sending a SIGTERM.  So ignore that for now.  Note that things are starting up again.

Go down lower.  It's throwing an H10 at the router.

Answer (score 2):

An exit code of 143 means that a kill process was sent and a SIGTERM signal terminated your process.  This is usually triggered whenever you execute any restart commands.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the console, it might crash as well... but will give you the reasoning. Usually it will be some small change you hadn't noticed or forgotten about that the Heroku error logs are bad at reporting.

run this

```
heroku run node
```

or

```
heroku restart
```