# Heroku web: Failed at start script

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I'm getting this

> Failed at the sequelize-demo@1.0.0 start script.

when deploying an express + react app. I think heroku is having an issue with `concurrently`.

[image]

What could i be doing wrong ? i referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347079/heroku-returns-process-exited-with-status-143), but the solution was a bit irrelevant to this application

Also referencing this

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-with-an-express-server-on-heroku-32244fe5a250

**Root folder package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sequelize-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "build": "concurrently \"cd client && npm run build\" \"npm build \"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "client": "cd ./client && npm start ",
    "server-prod": "node app.js",
    "server": "nodemon app.js",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others  \"npm run client\" \"npm run server\" ",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-flash": "0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "foreman": "^3.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "nodemailer": "^5.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-github": "^1.1.0",
    "passport-github2": "^0.1.11",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "7.9.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "sequelize": "^4.42.0",
    "sequelize-cli": "^5.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^6.1.2"
  }
}
```

**client/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.36",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "superagent": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
  
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0"
  }
}
```

**Profile**

```
web: npm run start
```

**Log**

> Users db and user table have been created
>
> State changed from starting to up
>
> Something is already running on port 32000.
>
> npm run client exited with code 0
>
> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
>
> npm run server exited with code SIGTERM  `
>
> npm ERR! sequelize-demo@1.0.0 start: `concurrently --kill-others  "npm run client" "npm run server"`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1 2019-04-11T07:26:41.326088+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> npm ERR!  2019-04-11T07:26:41.326282+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the sequelize-demo@1.0.0 start script.

[image]

Comment: You can't run 2 servers at once on heroku, must create another app for the  backend.

Comment: I think that when you deploy on the heroku you shoudl build your react files into bundle and server from node.js as public assets

Comment: What would be a good stack overflow question or any other resource to look at ? So what you are saying is that concurrently wont work when deploying to heroku ?

Comment: and their is a backend, check the repo. https://github.com/EliHood/mysequelizereact, let me know how you would change it to make it suitable to deploy

Comment: the client is the front end, and the server is on app.js

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, i didn't have a react build.

Which is what i learned from

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-with-an-express-server-on-heroku-32244fe5a250

*Now we need to make sure we have a **build folder** in our project before we push the project to the Heroku repository. Add the script below into your package.json file* - author of the blog

So i did a npm run build on the client directory.

then changed my **package.json** to

```
{
  "name": "sequelize-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "build": "concurrently \"cd client && npm run build\" \"npm build \"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "client": "cd ./client && npm start ",
    "server-prod": "node app.js",
    "server": "nodemon app.js",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "start:dev": "concurrently --kill-others  \"npm run client\" \"npm run server\" ",
    "heroku-postbuild":"NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-flash": "0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "foreman": "^3.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "nodemailer": "^5.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-github": "^1.1.0",
    "passport-github2": "^0.1.11",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "7.9.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "sequelize": "^4.42.0",
    "sequelize-cli": "^5.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^6.1.2"
  }
}
```

added this to **app.js**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
  //
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname = 'client/build/index.html'));
  })
}
//build mode
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/public/index.html'));
})
```

**Profile**

```
web: npm start
```