# Do I need to add an SSL cert to my Express API on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, ssl, heroku

I have a React app I created with npx create-react-app and an Express.js API I am using to make calls to my database all hosted on Heroku. I know that Heroku provides SSL certs but I don't know if that extends to my API calls. Is my API protected automatically or do I need something like `express-sslify`?

Comment: Possibly related: [SSL on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25148507/2873538)

Comment: Thank you! I feel like that's the best explanation I've been able to find.

Comment: Also, How to fix [Heroku SSL Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17631536/2873538), if you face it.