# How do you fix at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response"?

Tags: mysql, heroku, localhost, handlebars.js

**It is working on localhost but shutting down on heroku-app**

```
2020-08-15T02:15:31.851406+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-08-15T02:15:31.851963+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=yummy-burger-app.herokuapp.com request_id=dc7776de-d03f-4415-9448-fcd71e18efa1 fwd="100.38.167.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

**Feel free to reach me out if you need more inforamtion**

Answer (score 5):

had same issue ,solved it by changing my sever from https to http Check your sever configuration if you have https configured change it to http

i changed this

```
const server = https.createServer(httpOptions,app);
```

to this

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
```

and it worked for me

Comment: Thanks, worked for me as well, But do you have any explanation for that, why this issue occurs with https.

Comment: uwc ....heroku terminates ssl at thier load balancers, check this post out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148507/https-ssl-on-heroku-node-express

Answer (score 1):

try restarting the dynos on Heroku for H13 it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of worry, H13 is a type of error which occurs mostly when the user had exit without filling any form.

The easiest way to deal with this error is **you can restart your server on heroku.**

Answer (score 0):

**H13 - Connection closed without response**

This error is thrown when a process in your web dyno accepts a connection (request) but then closes the socket without executing the request. The connection is closed before any data is written, resulting in an H13.

One quick fix is to restart your Dynos in your heroku dashboard
click "more" then "restart all dynos"