# How to Solve Heroku Error AT code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, server-side

I had everything perfect, But suddenly I'm having this problem.DO not know why it is happenning.

Error:

heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/products/minhaj12113@gmail.com" host=lit-hamlet-04037.herokuapp.com request_id=03953580-e411-420d-b9ae-fe5e121f8b1d fwd="103.84.133.224" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63422176/how-do-you-fix-at-error-code-h13-desc-connection-closed-without-response

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/products/minhaj12113@gmail.com" host=lit-hamlet-04037.herokuapp.com request_id=03953580-e411-420d-b9ae-fe5e121f8b1d fwd="103.84.133.224" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https